# How the system of URIs should be designed?

Tags: android, android-listview

The `ListView` should display the content of the rather long code-list of products (say up to 100 thousands, i.e. nothing small). Because of that, effective and interactive searching is important. For the reasons not explained here, the filter value should be the part of URI...

I am using SQLite table, and the `LoadManager` and `CursorLoader` approach. Whenever the filter string changes, the cursor loader is reset, and the `onCursorLoader` is called, in turn. I am using the code like this:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    // Compose the URI based on whether the content should be filtered or not.
    // mCurFilter contains the filter value.
    Uri uri;
    if (mCurFilter.isEmpty()) {
        uri = DemoContentProvider.PRODUCTS_CONTENT_URI;
    } else {
        uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(DemoContentProvider.PRODUCTS_CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                                   Uri.encode(mCurFilter));
    }

    String[] projection = { ProductTable.COLUMN_ID,
                            ProductTable.COLUMN_CODE,
                            ProductTable.COLUMN_NAME,
                            ProductTable.COLUMN_STOCK,
                            ProductTable.COLUMN_PRICE };

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,
            uri, projection,
            null, null,     // no selection and selargs - filter value inside the URI
            orderInfo);     // info for sorting

    return cursorLoader;
}
```

Please, focus on the `uri` composition. Here the `PRODUCTS_CONTENT_FILTER_URI` was defined as:

```
public static final Uri PRODUCTS_CONTENT_FILTER_URI =
        Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
                   + "/" + ProductTable.CONTENT_PATH + "/filter");
```

The example may look like

```
content://cz.xxx.android.yyydemo.contentprovider/product/filter/abc
```

Where `abc` is the filter value entered by the user. I feel this URI design may not be correct (being a beginner in the area). For me, the following examples are OK:

```
content://AUTHORITY/product/     ... to get all products
content://AUTHORITY/product/123  ... to get the product with _id = 123
```

However, is the suffix like `filter/value` the good way to go?

**Update:** I will finally have several interrelated activities. Think in terms *customer*, *product*, *order head*, *order list*, *list of notes*. I am new to web-like system of adressing the data (i.e. to how the URI system should be designed). I would like to design the rules for my URIs so that it could be a kind of generalized. I know they are just strings, and I could do it whathever way. But I would like to do it *nicely* :)

For example: If the list of customers becomes big, the user may want to filter that list. I probably want to express filtering as a part of the URI. The list of products already *is* big. I would like to use tha same URI structure for the products. Now, the orders put customers and products together.

Say, I would like to display the list of products for the customer and for the order (order head) joined with the information about the ordered quantity of the products including the products with zero quantity (to be able to add them into the order). This way the combined list of products with the quantity is a kind of similar to the plain list of products (at least the same number of items in the list)-- the user may want to filter, change ordering, etc. However, the URI should contain the customer id, and the order id. When filtering is added, it should be also added to the URI. I know I can simply use the path like `/customer/123/order/456/filter/apple` where `apple` is the filter value, and the numbers `123` and `456` are the id's for the tables expressed by the previous part of the path...

From another point of view--for the previous example--the customer id, order id, and the filter value may be used as key-value pairs for keys being `'custome'`, `'order'`, and `'filter'` respectively. Moreover, I do not know what will be added in future.

I would like to start with the system of the applicatios URIs correctly. I guess it had to be done many times by the others. Can you share your experience? I would like to avoid the neccessity to redesign it later.

Comment: *is the suffix like filter/value the good way to go?* - this isn't important, it's just a string to be matched by the `UriMatcher` and you'll not work with it directly anyway, you'll use the URI. *Is the kind of filtering suitable for long lists?* - from what point are you asking?

Comment: @Luksprog: See the update. I did remove the part about *Filterable*, and I will add here later the reference to the separate question later.

Comment: @Luksprog: Please have look at the separated question http://stackoverflow.com/q/18144428/1346705

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. it is a matter of convenience how you structure it. I add "filter" URIs to reduce complexity of queries (e.g. multiple "WHERE" conditions, "JOIN"s)
2. ListView is reusing child views so it can handle much. Adapter filter is designed to reduce what is already in the adapter. As we are talking about large data I would prefer to not get it loaded in the first place.

Comment: Ad 2) I am aware of the mechanism of the recycled child views in the `ListView`. The second part of your answer... Does it mean that the filter just skips some of the cursor values and moves the cursor until it finds next record that satisfies the filtering condition? If WHERE can be used on the side of the "SQL engine", the ListView text filter is rather postprocessing of the data from the database, right?

Comment: Exactly, filter is just a post processing. It can be changed any time and we don't want to start new rawQuery() every time user narrows the search criteria. It is faster to work on what we've got already in memory.

Comment: ... unless it is not in memory. Is there any recommendation/hint when to use the `ListView` filtering, and when to reduce the data set via another SQL query?

Comment: @robotoaster *Exactly, filter is just a post processing. It can be changed any time and we don't want to start new rawQuery() every time user narrows the search criteria.* - that's true for arrays/list based adapters. For a `Cursor` based adapter the `Filter` will always make a new query(optimizing in between). @pepr There isn't such recommendation, it depends from case to case. Have a look at the CursorWrapper class if you want to filter the already available Cursor.

Comment: @robotoaster: Please have look at the separated question http://stackoverflow.com/q/18144428/1346705